# Injecting wcf channel with autofac

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I would like to use autofac inside a WCF service (using Autofac.Integration.Web) to resolve a dependency on a wcf channel. What I'm trying is something like this

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<CheckingService>();
    builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IAuthenticationService>(
                        new WSHttpBinding("wsHttpBinding_Common"),
                            new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthenticationServiceUrl"])).CreateChannel())
                        .SingleInstance();
    AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
}
```

Class using the channel:

```
public AuthorizationManager(IAuthenticationService authenticationServiceClient)
{
    AuthenticationServiceClient = authenticationServiceClient;
}
```

But I'm getting

```
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

When I'm trying to use WCF test client.

However if I just new the channel in the method the client doesn't complain:

so my understanding is that I'm doing something wrong in the binding but not sure what.

```
public AuthorizationManager()
{

    AuthenticationServiceClient = new ChannelFactory<IAuthenticationService>(
        new WSHttpBinding("wsHttpBinding_Common"),
        new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthenticationServiceUrl"])).CreateChannel();
}
```

So, correct me if I'm wrong, the problem should be in the binding but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Update

the ResourceServiceAuthorizationManager comes in the form of a nuget package

```
public class ResourceServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    public ResourceServiceAuthorizationManager();

    public IAuthenticationService AuthenticationServiceClient { get; set; }

    public Guid ResourceId { get; set; }

    public override bool CheckAccess(OperationContext operationContext);
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're trying to implement some specific authorization on your wcf service? If that is the case, why not implement using a membership provider?

Comment: We have our own service that we pull in via a nuget package that after some checks returns a claim. We were injecting the channelfactory using ninject service locator inside it, but then we needed to use Ninject as well in the Wcf service we are trying to access. Now I have removed ninject from the authentication service and therefore I have to satisfy its dependency of a channel (not really need to pass the factory itself). Not sure if I have explained it properly in just one commment

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand correctly but I think what you mean is: You made a reusable package which was depending on ninject. Now you removed ninject from the reusable package and let the dependency injection be done from outside the reusable package?

Comment: Before we were using Ninject to inject from outside of the reusable package and then using ServiceLocator inside it. Now, I removed DI from within the package so I need to pass the channel as a parameter. I'm trying to use DI outside though. Check my update

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are using the DI in the right way to use your WCF Service but the initialization could be

```
builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IAuthenticationService>(
    new WSHttpBinding("wsHttpBinding_Common"),
    new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthenticationServiceUrl"])) 
         .CreateChannel()).As<IAuthenticationService>().SingleInstance();
```